# Can't attach gdbserver to process through kubectl

Tags: gdb, google-kubernetes-engine, gdbserver, kubectl

It looks like I have some sort of permissions problem with kubectl. I have a Docker image, that contains server with native dynamic library + gdbserver. When I'm trying to debug Docker container running on my local machine all is fine. I'm using the following workflow:

1. start gdb
2. target remote | docker exec -i CONTAINER gdbserver - --attach PID
3. set sysroot /path/to/local/binary
4. Good to go!

But when I'm trying to do such operation with kubectl I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot attach to lwp 7: Operation not permitted (1)
>   Exiting
>   Remote connection closed

The only difference is step 2: 
`target remote | kubectl exec -i POD -- gdbserver - --attach PID`

Comment: Can you try `kubectl exec -it POD bash` and then `gdbserver --attach`. This will make debugging easier for you.

Comment: @ignite Thanks for response! Unfortunately I've got the same result. `Cannot attach to lwp 7: Operation not permitted (1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add ptrace() capabilities and seccomm profile in your yaml file.

> `--cap-add sys_ptrace`